# How can I prevent Dragon NaturallySpeaking capitalizing a word each time after I hit ctrl+left?

Tags: dragon-naturally-speaking

Each time I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>, Dragon NaturallySpeaking capitalizes the next word I dictate (just the first letter). What can I do to prevent this from happening?

Note that if I hit <kbd>←</kbd>, Dragon won't capitalize. Here is a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GeOCESWDLVw) showing the issue.

I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5, Windows 7 SP1, and this issue only occurs with non-standard applications.